# Looking for in memory database easy to use with Spring, Hibernate, JavaConfig and Maven

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am looking for in memory database easy to use with Spring, Hibernate, JavaConfig and Maven.

I am working on a example Spring Java Application using Spring, Hibernate, JavaConfig and Maven and I need a very easy to setup and use in memory database..

I would like to hear from others on which one will be easy to add to my project with JavaConfig, Maven, Hibrenate and Spring

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HSQLDB or H2 both work. I prefer H2 and use it with DbUnit for all of my JUnit unit tests as an embedded database. I have used both however and either will work fine with what you mentioned. The best part of either option is the plethora of examples on the interwebs :)

Comment: +1 for H2, used it at various projects, even in "embedded" production environments.

Answer (score 1):

We've successfully used [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/). It's very easy to start with; dialect supported by Hibernate.

Comment: anyway you can point me to sample code?

Comment: There's plenty material as HSQLDB is often used for demo applications. E.g., http://hsqldb.org/web/usagelinks.html has some references to how integrate with Spring, configure Hibernate etc.

Comment: .. and here you have full example of Spring+Hibernate+Hsqldb+Maven http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=620

Answer (score 1):

What used to be called Derby is bundled into JDK 7 now:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html

It doesn't get easier than that.